# error not outputting in login form

Tags: php, mysql

my code is

```
$query = "USE `davidedwardcakes`";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(!isset($result)){echo 'no' .  mysql_error();}


$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname = '$uname'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(!$result2){echo 'wrong username or password' . mysql_error(); var_dump($result2);}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{echo $row['uname'] . $row['pass']; var_dump($result2);}

echo 'submited';
```

I am trying to create a login form but i do not get any error output whenever i execute it with blank forms. Help please.

Comment: Try using `mysql_num_rows()` instead of just `if(!$result2)`

Comment: What does `var_dump($result2)` show?

Comment: @john, var-dump shows blank if i leave both uname and pass blank

Comment: @fred, how do i apply that here

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0){ // exists }`

Comment: @fred. that gave me a whole new error

Comment: Which is what exactly? Plus, are you using proper error reporting?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if you're not already doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the query will still run successfully if `$uname` is an empty string.  It will just have a zero-row result set.  As such, where you do this:

```
if(!$result2){echo 'wrong username or password' . mysql_error(); var_dump($result2);}
```

`$result2` will have a truthy value and your code in the conditional will not execute.

You should check `mysql_num_rows()` to determine if you have a non-empty result set.

By the way, there is no reason to run an actual `mysql_query()` to select the DB to use.  `mysql_select_db()` can be used for this purpose.

That being said, you should be using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me convert first your code to at least MySQLi instead of deprecated MySQL.

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$connect=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","yourDatabase"); /* REPLACE THE NECESSARY DATA INSIDE */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

/* $query = "USE `davidedwardcakes`";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(!isset($result)){echo 'no' .  mysql_error();} 
HIDE THIS FIRST, WHAT'S THE PURPOSE OF THIS CODE? */
*/

$uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['uname']); /* REPLACE THE NECESSARY POST DATA */

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname = '$uname'"; /* ADD ALSO HERE THE PASSWORD */
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)==0){ /* IF MATCHES FOUND NONE, ERROR */
echo "Wrong username or password";
var_dump($result2);
} /* END OF IF RESULT2 IS O */

else {

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
     echo $row['uname'] . $row['pass'];
     } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

echo 'submited';
var_dump($result2);
} /* END OF ELSE */

?>
```