# error in mysql query string

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form action = "index.php" method = "post">
username : <input type = "text" name = "uname" /><br>
password : <input type = "text" name = "pass" /><br>
submit : <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){echo $_SESSION['id'];}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'){

$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$db = "davidedwardcakes";
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'wtfiwwu');
$db_connect = mysql_selectdb($db, $connect);
if(!$db_connect){echo 'no';}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname ='$uname' AND pass = '$pass'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){//echo 'index failed'; var_dump($result);}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){echo $row['uname']
 . "<br>";

session_start();
echo '<a href = "test.php">peruse</a>';
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];}}

else{echo 'lol'; var_dump($query);}}
```

Whenever I want to login, i get the error:
    string 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname ='brown' AND pass = 'kenji'' (length=61)
meaning that theres a problem with my $query. If I remove the $pass query from $query it works fine but doesn't when it is included. Can anybody help please.

Comment: Do `AND pass ='$pass'";` you're dealing with a string, not an integer

Comment: my password is an integer ;-)

Comment: *"changed $pass to '$pass and got..."* no man, => add another quote  `WHERE uname ='$uname' AND pass ='$pass'";`

Comment: @fred, i did that before and got errors too. Anyway updated the question to reflect that

Comment: How about posting those errors?

Comment: So try `AND pass ='".$pass."'";` @brown.cn

Comment: @fred string 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname ='brown' AND pass ='kenji''

Comment: What is your password column type set at? Is it VARCHAR or something else?

Comment: All you posted is your **query**. Which is fine in and off itself (atleast speaking of syntax). Post your **error**-message please.

Comment: **Wait a minute,** you're using the wrong DB connection variable. You're using `$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);` where it should be `$result = mysql_query($query, $db_connect);`

Comment: no. $connect was defined to contain the server name and password but i cant' possibly post that here

Comment: You're using `$db_connect` in the first line of your code. That's the argument `mysql_query` (which is deprecated btw) expects.

Comment: you don't make it easy to help you.

Comment: I'm totally confused. Listen, scrap this project and use what the other guy gave you [**for an answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23643654/) in your other question. Plus, it's `mysqli_` which is better and you probably didn't see.

Comment: Had you shown us your DB connection code, all you had to do is replace your credentials with `xxx`'s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me convert your code to **MySQLi** at least. **MySQL** is already deprecated.

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$connect=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

/* REPLACE THE NECESSARY POST DATA BELOW AND PRACTICE ESCAPING STRINGS BEFORE USING IT INTO A QUERY TO AVOID SOME SQL INJECTIONS */
$uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
$pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname ='$uname' AND pass ='$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){ 
echo 'login failed';
var_dump($result);
}

else {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     echo $row['uname'];
     } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
echo 'Successfully Logged-in.';
var_dump($query);
} /* END OF ELSE */

?>
```

Comment: ah yes... I was referring to you in the other answer you gave, in a comment above. I just saw this now.

Comment: then he can fix the unsantised user inputs and the storming plain text passwords - haahahah

Comment: After all the work everyone's been through, yeah... the OP can do it himself. @Dagon

Comment: years later OP sincerely apologizes for this hardcore atrocity *facepalms at my own naivety*. Looking at this now, it's an utterly painful shoot-yourself-in-the-foot situation. My bad